# Integrals with measures on path spaces

Tags: probability-theory, measure-theory

Let $X_t$ for $t\in [0,T]$ be a $\mathbb R^d$-valued stochastic process with law $\rho\in \mathcal P(C([0,T];\mathbb R^d))$. Let $f:\mathbb R^d\rightarrow\mathbb R^d$ be a smooth function. Then
\begin{equation*}
\mathbb E_\rho \Bigl[\int_0^T f(X_t)dt \Bigr] = \int_0^T \mathbb E_{\rho_t}\left[f(X_t) \right] dt,
\end{equation*}
where $\rho_t=\mathrm{law}(X_t)$ and $\mathbb E_\nu$ denotes expectation w.r.t. measure $\nu$.

Question: Is this identity true, and if so why?

Motivation: I came across this identity in this paper (https://arxiv.org/pdf/1605.05878.pdf), specifically equation (2.2) where the authors directly move from law of paths to law of time marginals.

Ideas: One possible approach would be to use a Fubini-type result to exchange the time integral and the integral over $\mathcal X:=C([0,T];\mathbb R^d)$. But its still not clear to me how to go from the path measure to law at each time -- maybe using a push-forward $\pi_t:\mathcal X\rightarrow\mathbb R^d$ such that $\pi_t(X)=X_t$? My exposure to path measures (and even their definitions) is quite limited, and so any hints/ideas are greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is Fubini's Theorem.  $\mathbb{P}_{\rho}$ is a probability measure on $C([0,T];\mathbb{R}^{d})$, say, with respect to the Borel $\sigma$-algebra $\mathscr{B}$.  Now the family of random variables $\{X_{t}\}_{t \in [0,T]}$ given by $X_{t}(\omega) = \omega(t)$ for $\omega \in C([0,T]; \mathbb{R}^{d})$ forms a jointly measurable function $X : C([0,T]; \mathbb{R}^{d}) \times [0,T] \to \mathbb{R}^{d}$ given by $X(\omega,t) = X_{t}(\omega)$.  (That is, $X$ is measurable with respect to the product $\sigma$-algebra obtained from $\mathscr{B}$ and the Borel subsets of $[0,T]$.  This is immediate from its joint continuity.)

Applying Fubini's Theorem to $C([0,T];\mathbb{R}^{d}) \times [0,T]$ with product measure $\mathbb{E}_{\rho} \otimes \mathcal{L}^{1}$, we find
\begin{equation*}
\mathbb{E}_{\rho} \left[ \int_{0}^{T} f(X_{t}) \, dt \right] = \int_{0}^{T} \mathbb{E}_{\rho}(f(X_{t})) \, dt.
\end{equation*}
Given $t \in [0,T]$, if $\mathbb{P}_{\rho_{t}}$ is the law of $X_{t}$ under $\mathbb{P}_{\rho}$ (i.e. the pushforward of $\mathbb{P}_{\rho}$ under $X_{t}$), then $\mathbb{E}_{\rho}(f(X_{t})) = \mathbb{E}_{\rho_{t}}(f(X_{t}))$ so we get
\begin{equation*}
\mathbb{E}_{\rho} \left[ \int_{0}^{T} f(X_{t}) \, dt \right] = \int_{0}^{T} \mathbb{E}_{\rho_{t}}(f(X_{t})) \, dt.
\end{equation*}

Comment: Thank you for the answer. I am confused by the following: you have two objects $\mathbb P_{\rho}$ which is a probability measure on $C([0,T];\mathbb R^d)$ and $\mathbb P_{\rho_t}$ a probability measure on $\mathbb R^d$. How are these two objects connected? I understand that the push-forward $P_{\rho}$ is well-defined, but why is this push forward exactly $\mathbb P_{\rho_t}$ -- as far as I understand the latter object solves the Fokker-Planck equation.

Comment: Essentially why is $\mathbb{E}_{\rho}(f(X_{t})) = \mathbb{E}_{\rho_{t}}(f(X_{t}))$?

Comment: $\rho_{t}$ is the law of $X_{t}$ (by your own definition in the question).  In general, if $Y$ is a random vector on a probability space $(\Omega,\mathcal{F},\mathbb{P})$ and $\mu$ is its law, that means $\mathbb{E}(g(Y)) = \int_{\mathbb{R}^{d}} g(y) \, \mu(dy)$ for any bounded, continuous $g$.  (This is nothing other than the pushforward of $\mathbb{P}$ by $Y$.)  My guess is there is something else confusing you here; the Fokker-Planck equation has nothing to do with my answer.  Notice, in the generality of your question, it's not clear there is any Fokker-Planck equation involved.

Comment: First off, thank you for you answer. Well if $X_t$ is a stochastic differential equation, then $\rho$ is a probability measure on $C([0,T];\mathbb R^d)$ (an abstract object), whereas the object $\rho_t$ solves the Fokker-Planck equation. I am trying to understand why the push-forward of $\rho$ at time $t$, can be identified with the object which solves the Fokker-Planck equation.